# problems with pidgin-sipe and office 365

Tags: 14.04, pidgin, pidgin-sipe, office365

does anyone have problems logging into office365 IM via pidgin-sipe? This was working for me a week ago, then I have come back from holiday today and its not working, error is unable to authenticate however I triple checked the credentials, and they work fine for email

Answer (score 3):

this is apparently an issue in libsipe (http://sourceforge.net/p/sipe/bugs/285/?page=1), and has been fixed (I'm using a version compiled from source and it works).

Comment: Nice, building from the latest development git code works for me. Problem solved.